# Keycloak Userinfo endpoint validate_access_token error

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak

I'm running Keycloak and I want to call the userinfo endpoint with my OAuth2 Access Token.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0.5 start-dev
```

I can request an Access Token via:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "client_id=test_client" -d "client_secret=..." -d "username=test_user" -d "password=..." -d "grant_type=password" -d "scope=openid" "http://localhost:8080/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

Then, when I call the userinfo endpoint like this:

```
curl -H "Authorization: bearer [LONG TOKEN ...]","not-before-policy":0,"session_state":"5863414d-0bb6-4ebb-b543-aae4c1551b6f","not-before-policy":0,"session_state":"04a1a483-bd5c-400e-b6de-ead486c5bb7f" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "scope=openid" "http://localhost:8080/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo"
```

I'm getting no response, and I see in the logs:

```
2023-11-21 17:03:01,347 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-45) type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=3bbfd907-df70-4dd8-a1be-2c56116d05ef, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=172.17.0.1, error=invalid_token, auth_method=validate_access_token
```

Does anyone have an idea what I could do?